# Mongodb unmatch aggregate lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am very new in Mongodb and nodejs. I am trying to make attendance system and have multiple collection like attendances, shifts, leaves, Holidays. In the shifts collection have Week Off but obviously absents are not in record.
 
I have created a Playground as per my basic reach - [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SyDo7pjCvw0)

My attendance collections as follows.

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6249c77a99e5c26e50736c02"),
        "employee": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4"),
        "date": "2022-04-03T16:12:42.328Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("624a700199e5c26e50736c07"),
        "employee": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4"),
        "date": "2022-04-06T04:11:45.891Z"
    }
]
```

My shift collection as follow

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6272e84b6fc62f16bd0f337d"),
        "month": "2022-04",
        "employee": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4"),
        "shift": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6272e84b6fc62f16bd0f337c"),
                "date": "2022-04-03",
                "name": "Day"
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6272e84c6fc62f16bd0f337e"),
                "date": "2022-04-04",
                "name": "Week Off"
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("6272e8546fc62f16bd0f337f"),
                "date": "2022-04-5",
                "name": "Night"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here I need to get `Week Off` that have marked with employee and date but not related to attendance collections and as well as need employees wise `Absents` date in this same result which have no record and related to any collection.

I need something like this.

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6249c77a99e5c26e50736c02"),
        "date": "2022-04-03T16:12:42.328Z",
        "employee": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4"),
        "shift": {
            "_id": ObjectId("6272e84b6fc62f16bd0f337c"),
            "date": "2022-04-03",
            "name": "Day"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("622054b73b2eaac4b14442ee"), //Not required
        "date": "2022-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
        "employee": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4"),
        "shift": {
            "_id": ObjectId("6272e84c6fc62f16bd0f337e"),
            "date": "2022-04-04",
            "name": "Week Off"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b14442ee"),
        "date": "2022-04-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "employee": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4"),
        "shift": {
            "_id": ObjectId("6272e8546fc62f16bd0f337f"),
            "date": "2022-04-05",
            "name": "Night"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("624a700199e5c26e50736c07"), //Not required
        "date": "2022-04-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "employee": ObjectId("622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4"),
        "absent": true
    }
]
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's still unclear. What field decides absents

Comment: I have added required JSON. Please have a look. @Gibbs

Comment: This is still unclear. What is "May or may not"? Why do you want on 2 of 3 shifts in the results?

Comment: Actually, this  _id belongs to the attendance collection _id. In the attendance collection, may not have Week off, absent, holiday and leave relation. So I mention this. @nimrodserok

Comment: We need your expected result from the data that is in the playground. It is not clear since you publish expected results from other data